# How to make changes to mesh after animating

Tags: animation, mesh, bones, pose-mode

I have animated a bird. However I forgot to add eyes so I want to add them now, but when I change from Edit mode to  Object mode in order to add new eyes the bones, the bird itself gets deformed to pose animation, leaving eyes behind.
Edit Mode: [image]

Object Mode: [image]

Answer (score 0):

I watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2fx8TMQDoc and it help me to attach eyes to body itself, but I had to put eyes higher in mesh to make it good in animation. Tell me please if you know how to put them the right way. [image: Edit mode]

[image: Object mode with animation]

Comment: Editing the question or asking another one is better